# Haskell use of map and composed function

Tags: function, haskell, dictionary, functional-programming, composition

Ok, I can't figure this one out even though I have an idea what it's doing...

```
let t = ["APE", "MONKEY", "DONKEY"]
```

Now consider three cases:

```
map (length.group) t
(map length.group) t
map (map length.group) t
```

This returns these three answers:

```
[3,6,6]
[1,1,1]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Now, can someone explain to me in details what's going on. A crucial part of this question is that I assume that map needs a list to work on and I don't see two maps being passed in the third case for example.

Comment: Hint: `map (f . g) = map f . map g`, so you should be able to figure out what is going on by looking at the result of `group t` and `map group t`.

Comment: Note that your 2nd one isn't parsed the way you've got it spaced out.  It's actually parsed as `((map length) . group) t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map (length.group) t
```

This composes the functions `length` and `group`. The result is a function that takes a list (string) and returns the number of "groups" in that list (where a group is a sequence of the same character repeating 1 or more times, so "abc" contains 3 groups and so does "aabbcc").

This function is then applied to each string in `t` using `map`.

```
(map length.group) t
```

Here the function `map length` (which takes the length of each sublist in a list of lists) is composed with the function `group` and the composed function is applied to `t`. In other words it's the same as `map length (group t)`.

```
map (map length.group) t
```

Here the function `map length . group` is applied to each string in `t`, i.e. `map length (group str)` is calculated for each string `str` in `t`.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the "`length.`" from all your cases, and see if that helps answer your question.  It'll simplify the problem and the answer might show you a little better what's going on.

Or, factoring the third one, it becomes

```
map (map length.group) ["APE", "MONKEY", "DONKEY"]
--make parse order explicit
map ((map length) . group) ["APE", "MONKEY", "DONKEY"]
--do mapping
[((map length) . group) "APE", ((map length) . group) "MONKEY", ((map length) . group) "DONKEY"]
--use (f.g) x == f (g x)
[(map length) (group "APE"), ...]
[(map length) ["A", "P", "E"], ...]
[[1, 1, 1], ...]
```

Also try using some animals like "EEL" or "BEE" or "LLAMA" to see anything other than 1's in the final result.

Comment: Thanks! Good suggestion to stick with animals too ;) I get it sort of... if you remove "length" though, the last one doesn't work... how come?

Comment: If you don't remove the dot after length, if you follow the reduction above, in the last line you get `[(map) ["A", "P", "E"],...]`, which obviously doesn't mean anything. If you do remove the dot, you end up with `[(map group) "APE",...]`", which equals `[[group 'A',group 'P',group 'E'],...]`, which doesn't mean anything either.

Comment: I don't follow you... with length.group in the last one I end up with ["A","P","E"] which after length gives [1,1,1] which is passed along to the "outer" map and put in the resulting list... shouldnt just ["A","P","E"] be passed along in the same manner? Instead I get an error complaining about "expecting [[[a0]]] but finding [[Char]]... Sorry, this may seem unimportant but it's part of my understanding for all of this...

Comment: No, you've still got that inner `map` in there, and so it's expecting to map *something* to `["A","P","E"]`, but there's no function to map to it.  Hence, weird error.  I think what you're imagining is the output of `map (group) ["APE", "MONKEY", "DONKEY"]`, not `map (map group) ["APE", "MONKEY", "DONKEY"]`

Comment: Ah, I think I got it now... that actually made a big difference, thanks a lot :)